# Parsing table with rvest returning empty list

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest

I am tried the following code to parse the table
of information from the [ftp site](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/):

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'rvest':
#>   method            from
#>   read_xml.response xml2
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
#> Loading required package: xml2
ghcn_url <- "ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/"
# Reading the HTML code from the website
ghcn_html <- xml2::read_html(x = ghcn_url)
ghcn_html %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE)
#> list()
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

It currently returns an empty list i.e `list()`

Could anyone please explain how to obtain a tibble
with 3 required columns: "Name", "Size", "Date Modified".

When inspecting the page source there is a `<table>` tag. So felt the above should work.
Could anyone please show how to correct the code?

Comment: If you want to get climate data from noaa, use https://github.com/ropensci/rnoaa or https://github.com/ropensci/FedData/

Comment: Thanks @Tung. I am aware of those sources. What I'm trying to do here is get a tibble of the date/ time of updates for these retrospective data files. So I don't have to check this info manually by going to the website. The data download are done using the package API you have listed above. Could you please assist?